# How to trick react router into thinking `/` is the mount directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, github-pages

Let's say I have a simple react app:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import App from './App';
import About from './components/pages/About'
import Header from './components/layout/Header';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Route path = "/" component={Header} />
      <Route exact path="/" component= {App} />
      <Route path="/about" component = {About} />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

where `Header` is like

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Header = () => (
    <header style={headerStyle}>
        <h1>My Fancy App</h1>
        <div><Link to="/" style={headerLinkStyle}>Home</Link> | <Link to="/about" style={headerLinkStyle}>About</Link></div>
    </header>
)

const headerStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',

    padding: '.25em',

    background: '#333',
    color: 'white'
}

const headerLinkStyle = {
    color: 'white'
}

export default Header
```

This is working fine.

The problem, now, is when I host this on github pages.

Because of how github pages works, the page will be hosted on `https://myGithubAccount.github.io/my-repo-name/`

If I click the `Home` link, however, I won't be redirected to `https://myGithubAccount.github.io/my-repo-name/`, I will instead be redirected to `https://myGithubAccount.github.io/`

and similarly, the `About` link won't take me to `https://myGithubAccount.github.io/my-repo-name/about` but to `https://myGithubAccount.github.io/about`.

Now by some react witchery, that actually works -- so long as you don't try to reload the page -- but it's clearly suboptimal.

I can, of course, just change all my usages of `/` to `/my-repo-name`, but if I go down that rabbit hole, I will have to go back and change it when I later give it a proper URL and then again when I host it somewhere else, and then again when ...

I'd rather have react consider `/` to be wherever the application is hosted (which is how it should be for properly encapsulated web apps).

I.e. on localhost, `/` will be `localhost:3000/` and on github pages, `/` will be `https://myGithubAccount.github.io/my-repo-name/`

How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi perfect, thank you. I should mention though, that setting the `homepage` propety in the `package.json` was not sufficient because I had already done that. `<Router basename = {process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>`, seems to work fine, though. Do you want to expand your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Good to hear , I could help you . I have posted the answer for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps :

1. **Set the basename**

> ```
> <Router basename={'/directory-name'}>
>   <Route path='/' component={Home} />
>   {/* … */}
> </Router>
> ```

2. **Set the app homepage**(in package.json file)

> `"homepage": "https://myapp.com/directory-name",`

3. **Update the Routes**

> ```
> Router basename={'/subdirectory'}>
>   <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={Home} />
>   <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/news`} component={News} />
>   <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/about`} component={About} />
> </Router>
> ```

4. **Update the Links**

> `<Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/page-path`}>…</Link>`

For detailed information , have a look at this link https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1

Comment: By version 2 you mean?