# React Github page react-router routing query parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, navigation, query-string

I'm trying to make my own page, I'm having trouble with routing.

Since the page will be loaded on `Github`, it will have an address like this:

```
nameUser.github.io/nameProject
```

The site with several pages, let's consider two pages for the moment let's call them "`page1`" and "`page2`".

If you use such routing: `nameUser.github.io/nameProject/pageNumber`

To access one of the pages, `Github` gives an error.

So I'm opting for a routing where the page is passed as parameters.

I will have such an address: `nameUser.github.io/nameProject/?page=pageNumber`

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
nameUser.github.io/nameProject             -> page1
nameUser.github.io/nameProject/            -> page1
nameUser.github.io/nameProject/?page=      -> page1
nameUser.github.io/nameProject/?page=page1 -> page1
nameUser.github.io/nameProject/?page=page2 -> page2
nameUser.github.io/nameProject/?page=page5 -> pageError or page1
```

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nu558?file=/demo.js)

This is the code being used to print the referenced page:

```
  {routeObj.map(({ path, obj }, key) => {
    if (path.includes(page)) {
      return obj;
    } else return <div>No found</div>;
  })}
```

But that's not very correct, the reasons are that:

1. Don't consider that page doesn't exist.
2. It does unnecessary loops, even when the page is found on the first iteration, it continues with all possible loops.
   You can also see it in the example I posted.

I tried using `<Switch>` and `<Route>`, but I couldn't get them to work.

On codesandbox, when I click on a page, it also gives me other problems, which I normally don't get locally.

Can you give me a hand?

[image]

Comment: this is unnecessary work around.  Check this link https://medium.com/@bennirus/deploying-a-create-react-app-with-routing-to-github-pages-f386b6ce84c2

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640531/how-to-trick-react-router-into-thinking-is-the-mount-directory/62641238#62641238

Comment: @MonzoorTamal: I'm trying as you indicated, but the error page path: "*" doesn't work

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi: I've tried but don't understand how to make it work.